# Find id string, copy bytes util 00 filled sequence and save it to a file

Tags: c++, bin

Well I'm trying to extract some files that are within a binary file, my method at the moment is to find the idString that identifies the begin of the file, copy the bytes until find a sequence of 00, and save this result in a separate file.

this is my current code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int writeFile(char * array, string name){
    std::ofstream fs(name.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    fs.write(array, sizeof(array));
    fs.close();
}


int main () {
  streampos size;
  char * memblock;
  char * DATA;
  char * NEW_FILE;

  ifstream file ("DATA.BIN", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
 if (file.is_open())
 {
   size = file.tellg();
   memblock = new char [size];
   file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
   file.read (memblock, size);
   file.close();

DATA = memblock;
delete[] memblock;

int i = 0;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;


string temp = "";
string t = "";
string temp1 = "";

    for(i=0;i<300843008;i++){
        temp = temp + DATA[i];
        a = a + 1;
        if(b == 0){
        if(a == 4){
            if(temp == "RIFF"){
                b = 1;
                NEW_FILE[0] = 'R';
                NEW_FILE[1] = 'I';
                NEW_FILE[2] = 'F';
                NEW_FILE[3] = 'F';
            }
            a = 0;
            temp == "";
        }
    }

        if(b == 1){
            NEW_FILE[i] = DATA[i];
            if(DATA[i] == 00){
                c = c + 1;
                if(c == 32){
                    temp1 = "file" + c;
                    writeFile(NEW_FILE,temp1);
                    b = 0;
                    c = 0;
                }
            }

        }

    }

 }
else cout << "error";
return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the program just closes as soon as it opened, apparently it crashes when going to run this line "temp = temp + DATA [i];" But I have no idea how to fix it ...
Could anyone help me?

~ I hope you understood my problem, my English is very bad ~

Comment: why you have hard coded this number 300843008? should be using the file size right?

Comment: Initially I thought it was the "sizeof ()" that caused the problem, then replace the value of size mannualy, that at the end that was not the problem, but I ended up not changing back to "sizeof()" again.

Comment: So you are opening a 300MB file? You are probably overstepping the bounds of the DATA array. Did you step through the code in the debugger?  What is the value of size?

Comment: Why do you allocate `memblock`, read into it, assign another pointer to the memory, then delete the memory?  This means that `DATA` is a dangling pointer (memory leak).  Once memory is `delete`d, you should not access it (keeping a pointer to deleted memory makes no sense either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet is questionable:

```
   size = file.tellg();
   memblock = new char [size];  // <-- Allocation
   file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
   file.read (memblock, size);
   file.close();

   DATA = memblock;             // <-- Assign 2nd pointer to *same memory*
   delete[] memblock;           // <-- Delete memory pointed to by same pointers.
```

Especially the last two lines.

You allocate the memory:

```
   memblock = new char [size];
```

Then assign another pointer to **point to the same memory**:

```
   DATA = memblock;
```

Then delete the memory:

```
   delete[] memblock;
```

The assignment operation: `DATA = memblock` **does not make a copy of the memory**.  The operation makes the `DATA` point point to the same place as `memblock`.  In other words *pointer* `DATA` and *pointer* `memblock` point to the same place.

You code deletes the memory that `DATA` points to.  Not a good thing.  See also "memory leak".  This is undefined behavior.  Another process may write to the data that has been deleted or the memory may be re-used by other allocations in your program.  In either case, you can't expect the data to be valid after it has been deleted.

Comment: That was the problem ... ^^ thank you, now my only problem is to optimize the execution of the code that is taking a long time now, but in essence is working properly.